# array allocated by malloc gets lost

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, malloc

I'm trying to implement a neural network, but the initialization is not working, but I can't spot my mistake:

```
typedef struct{
    int numWeights;
    double* weights;
    double wBias;
}NeuronTanh;

typedef struct{
    int numNeurons;
    NeuronTanh* neurons;
}Layer;

typedef struct{
    int numLayers;
    Layer* layers;
}Network;

//--------------------------------

void initializeNetwork(Network* network){
    //malloc stuff
    network->numLayers = NUMBER_LAYERS;
    network->layers = malloc(NUMBER_LAYERS * sizeof(Layer));
    network->layers[0].numNeurons = 1
    network->layers[1].numNeurons = 4
    network->layers[2].numNeurons = 2

    for(int currentLayerIndex=0; currentLayerIndex<network->numLayers;++currentLayerIndex){
        Layer l = network->layers[currentLayerIndex];
        l.neurons = malloc(l.numNeurons * sizeof(NeuronTanh));
        for(int j=0; j<l.numNeurons; ++j){
            if(currentLayerIndex==0){
                l.neurons[j].numWeights = 2;
            }else{
                l.neurons[j].numWeights = network->layers[currentLayerIndex-1].numNeurons;
            }
            l.neurons[j].weights = malloc((1+l.neurons[j].numWeights) * sizeof(double));
            randomizeNeuron(&(l.neurons[j]));
        }
    }
 printNetwork(*network);
}
```

My problem exactly now is, that in the innermost for loop I can print all weights after *randomizeNeuron(...)* but if I want to print all weights or neurons in the end of the function, the neuron arrays are NULL, while the layers array was initialized fine. Why is the neuron (and weights) array NULL?

**EDIT**

```
 printNetwork(Network network){
    fprintf(stderr, "Layers:%i\n",network.numLayers);
    for(int numLayer = 0; numLayer<network.numLayers; ++numLayer){
        fprintf(stderr, "Layer %i -------------------\n",numLayer);
        for(int numNeuron=0; numNeuron<network.layers[numLayer].numNeurons; ++numNeuron){
            fprintf(stderr, "Neuron %i: ", numNeuron);
            fprintf(stderr, "number of neurons: %i: ", network.layers[numLayer].numNeurons);
            if(network.layers[numLayer].neurons != NULL){
                for(int numWeight=0; numWeight<network.layers[numLayer].neurons[numNeuron].numWeights; ++numWeight){
                    fprintf(stderr, "%f ",network.layers[numLayer].neurons[numNeuron].weights[numWeight]);
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", network.layers[numLayer].neurons[numNeuron].wBias);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is

```
Layers:3
Layer 0 -------------------
Neuron 0: number of weights: 2: Neuron 1: number of weights: 2: Layer 1 -------------------
Neuron 0: number of weights: 4: Neuron 1: number of weights: 4: Neuron 2: number of weights: 4: Neuron 3: number of weights: 4: Layer 2 -------------------
Neuron 0: number of weights: 1:
```

Comment: Could you please add printing code for both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
Layer l = network->layers[currentLayerIndex];
l.neurons = malloc(l.numNeurons * sizeof(NeuronTanh));
```

The line with malloc doesn't effect `network->layers[currentLayerIndex].neurons`.

Lets assume that `network->layers[currentLayerIndex].neurons` has address **X**. After

```
Layer l = network->layers[currentLayerIndex];
```

`l.neurons` has address **X** since it was coppied from `network->layers[currentLayerIndex].neurons`.

Now `malloc` returns address **Y**, which is assigned to `l.neurons` while `network->layers[currentLayerIndex].neurons` remains **X**.

Thus `network->layers[currentLayerIndex]` is not effected by the further initializatins. All those initializations are performed on `l`.

**Edit:**

Possible solution would be to assign `l.neurons` back to `network->layers[currentLayerIndex].neurons` after the inialization is done.

Comment: So I should change the line to `Layer* l = &network->layers[currentLayerIndex]` and work with this pointer?

Comment: @Jonas This is also an option. You can also assign the poiner back to the `network->layers`. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Lop, you spotted the error, now it's working.